# drawing two matrix side by side

Tags: matrices

Any suggestions to draw these two matrix[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion for your drawing is put below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[y_D=\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\mathsf{diag}(\gamma_{1}s_{1},\ldots,\gamma_{n}s_{n})}{\tau}\\
{\mathbf{0}}_{N\times(P-1)\times N}\\
\ldots \ldots \\
{\mathbf{0}}_{EX\times N}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad x_D=\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{J_{P}\,\otimes\,\mathsf{diag}(s_{1},\ldots,s_{n})}{\tau}\,{\mathbf{0}}_{NP\times EX}\\
{\mathbf{0}}_{N\times(NP)+ EX}\\
\ldots \ldots \\
{\mathbf{0}}_{EX\times NP} \qquad I_{EX}\times 1/c
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm grateful to you. Thank you for taking the time to provide me with the right answer

Comment: @haithem i hope that there are not mistakes. :-)